# Создать конструктор объектов

Tags: javascript

Снова прошу помощи у сообщества.
/*2.Создать конструктор объектов «Государство», содержащий в себе свойства: название страны, столица, население, глава государства. При вводе данных с клавиатуры проводить проверку данных на достоверность и «на лету» создавать новые объекты этого класса. Прекратить ввод, если название не введено или нажата клавиша ESC. Сохранять данные в массиве объектов. Затем вывести данные в окно браузера в виде таблицы. Для вывода применить созданный самостоятельно метод объекта. */

```
<script>
        function State(name, capital, population, head) {
        if (typeof name !== "string") {
            alert("Вы ввели неправильное значение. Обновите страницу и попробуйте еще раз");
        } else {
            this.name = name;
        }
        if (typeof capital !== "string") {
            alert("Вы ввели неправильное значение. Обновите страницу и попробуйте еще раз");
        } else {
            this.capital = capital;
        }

        this.population = parseInt(population);
        if (isNaN(population) || population < 10000) {
            alert("Вы ввели неправильное значение или маловато народу в государстве. Обновите страницу и попробуйте еще раз");
        } else {
            this.population = population;
        }

        if (typeof head !== "string") {
            alert("Вы ввели неправильное значение. Обновите страницу и попробуйте еще раз");
        } else {
            this.president = head;
        }

        this.displayInfo = function() {

            document.write("Государство: " + this.name + "; + Столица: " + this.capital + "Население: " + this.population + "; + Президент: " + this.president + "<br/>");
        }
    }



    var StateArray = [];

    do {
        var name = prompt("Введите название государства(ESC, Отмена - окончание ввода данных):");
        if (name === null) {
            break
        }
        var capital = prompt("Введите столицу государства(ESC, Отмена - окончание ввода данных):");
        if (capital === null) {
            break
        }
        var population = prompt("Введите население государства (число)(ESC, Отмена - окончание ввода данных):");
        if (population === null) {
            break;
        }
        var head = prompt("Введите имя главы государства(ESC, Отмена - окончание ввода данных):");
        if (head === null) {
            break;
        }
        console.log(name, capital, population, head);

        StateArray.push(name, capital, population, head)


    } while (true);
    if (confirm("Если вы закончили ввод данных, вывести список?")) {
        for (var state in StateArray)

    </script>
```

я не доделала. Но, кажись, работает. В консоль выводит.

Comment: Вы вообще понимаете, что делаете? =(

Comment: Для начала, уберите вашу "лестницу" циклов `do` (не оконченных к тому же). Оставьте только самый верхний `do` и допишите в самый конец `} while (true);` От Вас требуется массив объектов - добавьте переменную `var StateArray = [];` В нее будете добавлять готовые объекты `State`. Вывод в браузер в виде таблицы - пишите, пожалуйста, сами. Покажете здесь - ещё чего посоветуем